# opening Runtime Access from Excel VBA to Specific Form and Record

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an Excel Workbook that provides a suite of reports.  The data comes from an Access database, ole db connection etc.

I have a switchboard type screen on the main Excel worksheet, with buttons to view the various reports, and to open Access to an add new data form, and to an edit selected data form.  I have all this working perfectly on my machine, with Full Access installed, using the following code in an Excel Module.

```
Sub OpenFormAmend()

Dim ac As Object
Dim strID As String

strID = Range("IniId").Value


On Error Resume Next


Set ac = GetObject(, "Access.Application")

 If ac Is Nothing Then
 Set ac = GetObject("", "Access.Application")
 ac.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Database.accdb"
 ac.DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Amend", , , "ID =" & strID
 ac.UserControl = True
 Set ac = Nothing
 End If

AppActivate "Microsoft Access"
ac.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Database.accdb"
ac.DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Amend", , , "ID =" & strID

End Sub
```

This however doesn't do anything at all on a user's machine with Access Runtime only.  I have been able to get the database to open with the following code pinched from a similar question here.

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run ("""C:\Database.accdb""")
```

But I have no clue how to go about getting the above open to the particular form, or to open to the selected record.  Any help on getting started would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling GetObject() again after it has failed to return a currently running instance. Your second call should be to CreateObject().

Using On Error Resume Next is understandable before the first GetObject call, but you should turn on error reporting immediately afterwards (e.g. On Error Goto MyErrorHandler) otherwise you will have no idea what has gone wrong...